# UDP winsock server c++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, winsock

I'm doing some socket programming with a UDP connection. I have my server written (which also takes an offset for a NTP server), but when I unit test it, it fails at the recvfrom function. I'm new to winsock programming, and network programming in general, so I'm not sure exactly where to go from here. Here is my code:

```
NtpServer::NtpServer(u_short portnum, const std::chrono::nanoseconds desiredOffset) : portnum(0), client_length(0), bytes_received(0), current_time(0), desiredOffset(0)
{
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0)
    {

        std::cerr << "Could not open Windows connection" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create socket." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    //blocking enabled
    u_long iMode = 0;

    iResult = ioctlsocket(sd, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        std::cerr << "ioctlsocket failed with error: " << iResult << std::endl;


    memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(portnum);


    if (bind(sd, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR *>(&server),
        sizeof(server)) == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not bind name to socket" << std::endl;
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
    getResult(desiredOffset);
}
```

and the getResult function:

```
void NtpServer::getResult(const std::chrono::nanoseconds desiredOffset)
{
    ntp_data ntpData = ntp_data();
    //struct for timeout
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 10;  // 10 Secs Timeout 
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    while (1)
    {
        client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        /* Receive bytes from client */
        bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
        if (bytes_received < NTP_PACKET_MIN)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << std::endl;
            closesocket(sd);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0);
        }



        /* Check for time request */
        if (strcmp(readBuffer, "GET TIME\r\n") == 0)
        {
            /* Get current time */
            system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto timepointoffset = (now + desiredOffset).time_since_epoch();
            double current_value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(timepointoffset).count();

            unpack_ntp(&ntpData, (unsigned char*)readBuffer, bytes_received);
            make_packet(&ntpData, NTP_CLIENT, current_value);
            pack_ntp((unsigned char *)sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MIN, &ntpData);


            /* Send data back */
            if (sendto(sd, sendBuffer,
                (int)sizeof(sendBuffer), 0,
                (struct sockaddr *)&client, client_length) !=
                (int)sizeof(current_time))
            {
                std::cerr << "Error sending datagram." << std::endl;
                closesocket(sd);
                WSACleanup();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();


}
```

Comment: too much code, to little details on actual problem.

Comment: Well if I try and run my unit test it says "The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. To investigate further, enable local crash dumps either at the machine level or for process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe." When I debug, when it gets to the recvfrom function, the "bytes_received" is less than NTP_PACKET_MIN.

Comment: thanks i'll delete my comment

Comment: how many bytes is it receiving?

Comment: This is a .dll so I'm not sure if there is a way to test it directly. I know that from a previous 'if' block, it's getting -1 though, which I believe signals an error.

Answer (score 1):

You must test for errors from `recvfrom()` -- you're setting SO_RCVTIMEO, so you can expect the receives to timeout.

Do you ***really*** want to enable read timeouts? If so, when you set SO_RCVTIMEO, set `tv.tv_usec = 0`. You're leaving it uninitialized. If tv_usec happens to be an invalid value (less than 0 or greater than 999,999) then the `setsockopt()` call should fail.

Comment: My task requires that I use a timeout, yes. I think i'm confused that you're saying i'm leaving tv.tv_usec uninitialzed. Don't I have it set to 10?

Comment: You're setting `tv.tv_sec` (the whole second part of the timeout) to 10, but there's also a `tv.tv_usec` component which is a count of microseconds and must be between 0 and 999,999 inclusive. For example, if you want the timeout to be roughly 10 seconds, do `tv.tv_sec = 10; tv.tv_usec = 0;`. If you want the timeout to be roughly 10.5 seconds, do `tv.tv_sec = 10; tv.tv_usec = 500000;`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html for more details.